# P2P network design

Tags: p2p

I'm attempting to design a P2P network where all peers share the same data, as well as make changes to it. Without getting into the consensus portion (ie assume that only one node will make changes to the data at one time).

How would I make sure that all peers are connected to other peers in a fault tolerant way? I can only think of one way, and that is that each peer can request more peers from another peer, but how do I make sure that connections are distributed as evenly as possible, without one peer overloading on TCP connections, while another peer might barely have any connections? Or even how can I prevent all peers splitting into two separate groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like bittorrent's [canonical peer priority](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0040.html) ([github link](https://github.com/bittorrent/bittorrent.org/blob/6bc1256707b8416a62f43e4ce20cfdf280e6c435/beps/bep_0040.rst)) which calculates a preference-order by hashing identifiers of both endpoints together should allow nodes to reach a pseudo-random layout of the overlay while avoiding nodes being "left out". Hashing both identities together results in a different but globally agreed on ordering from the perspective of each peer, thus constructing a randomized layout. As the number of edges per node increases the chance of the network splitting will rapidly go towards zero.

And you can put a limit on the number of connections that each peer accepts, that will force others to go look elsewhere once it is saturated.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Each peer will prioritize other peers based on that crc32, the higher the result the more it will want to keep it as a peer?

Comment: and kick out others if needed to make room for it within the connection cap, yes

Comment: Cane you edit your answer to include the article incase of a dead link? then I'll mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Other question, how should it handle peers with the same prototype? First come first serve?

Comment: Correction: prototype was supposed to be priority

Comment: That thing is a specification, I don't think including specifications wholesale is the purpose of quoting on SO. I already sketched the algorithm anyway in abstract terms. As for the tie-breaking: it does not really matter, with 32bits the collision probability is not that high.

Comment: Ah. I thought SO had a linking rule that prevents dead Links.